# Data Binding part of a label in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Label in Xamarin forms.
I got to display a text which is basically a sentence but part of that string contains a number which I get from an api call and rest of the string is fixed.

I want to use data binding to set that part.
Example :

Text could be like :  "You can win {0} dollars for sure"

{0} value comes from api and want to use data binding to bind it.

Need the syntax to be used to bind this kind of string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use modle bind to data in your label.Just like this:
in xaml :

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Name,StringFormat='You can win {0} dollars for sure'}" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

in ContentPage, should bind context:

```
 nativeDataTemple = new NativeDataTemple();
 BindingContext = nativeDataTemple;
```

and Molde(**NativeDataTemple** you custom) should contain the binding property,like this:

```
private string name = "520";
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

and in your modle ,when Name value change in the background,add **INotifyPropertyChanged** to the modle,and method

```
 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

then where you want change the data ,jusst do that:

```
nativeDataTemple.Name = "550";
```

if have problem ,you can refer to this[Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)

Answer (score 2):

use spans within a Label

```
<Label>
  <Label.FormattedText>
    <FormattedString>
      <Span Text="You can win " />
      <Span Text="{Binding DollarAmount}" />
      <Span Text=" dollars for sure." />
    </FormattedString>
  </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```