# DataBindings not updating with OnPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Building my first app with Xamarian.Forms. I have my basic menu and home page built with some labels and a button so that I can bind some data and a method and to make sure the logic code for my game is working. I got my data bindings working as far as the labels go, they appear on screen. However I was unsure if my bindings weren't updating or if my command wasn't binding. So I commented out the ICommand, removed the binding and put the method to advance a turn into the code behind my xaml. Even after this, the data is not updating when the button is clicked which leads me to believe it is a problem with my OnPropertyChanged and the data bindings. I've searched the web and related questions, I've implemented a couple different ways of writing the gets and sets for the bindings, wrote my OnPropertyChanged function a few different ways and still nothing happens when the toolbar button on the home page is clicked.

Here is my HomePageViewModel.cs containing INotifyPropertyChanged

***Edited to reflect changes made since getting the day value to update:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Engine;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class HomePageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static Player _player = World.Player1;

        public string Day = World.TrueDay.ToString();

        public string MoneyValue = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(World.Player1.PlayerMoney)).ToString();

        public string CurrentLocation = _player.CurrentLocation.Name;


        public HomePageViewModel()
        {
            OnTurn = new Command(execute: On1Turn);
        }

        public ICommand OnTurn { get; private set; }

        public string CurrentDay
        {

            get { return Day; }

            set { Day = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }

        }

        public string Money
        {

            get { return MoneyValue; }

            set { MoneyValue = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public string PlayerLocation
        {

            get { return CurrentLocation; }

            set { CurrentLocation = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        void On1Turn()
        {

            World.TrueDay = World.TrueDay + 1;

            CurrentDay = World.TrueDay.ToString();

            World.Player1.PlayerMoney = World.Player1.PlayerMoney + 1000;

            MoneyValue = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(World.Player1.PlayerMoney)).ToString();

            OnPropertyChanged(Money);

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Here is my HomePage.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:TestApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestApp.HomePage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local1:HomePageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="+24hrs" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"  />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


    <StackLayout Padding="20">

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Money:" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblPlayerMoney"  Text="{Binding Money, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,-40,0,0">
            <Label Text="Current Location:" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblPlayerLocation" Text="{Binding PlayerLocation, Mode=OneWay}"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Current Day:" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblCurrentDay" Text="{Binding CurrentDay, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>




</ContentPage>
```

And the HomePage.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Engine;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TestApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //BindingContext = new HomePageViewModel();
        }

        private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            World.TrueDay = World.TrueDay + 1;

            World.Player1.PlayerMoney = World.Player1.PlayerMoney + 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

Any insight into the issue would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to Xamarian.Forms and the OnPropertyChanged feature in general. Thanks for the time!

EDIT******

Here is the World.cs were I set the properties if it helps

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Engine
{
    public class World
    {
        public static decimal TrueDay = 1;
        //public string LocationText = Player1.CurrentLocation.Name.ToString();

        public static Player Player1;

        public static readonly List<Location> Locations = new List<Location>();

        public const int LOCATION_ID_OSHAWA = 1;
        public const int LOCATION_ID_TORONTO = 2;

        public static void GenerateWorld()
        {
            PopulateLocations();
            Player1 = new Player("Jordan", LocationByID(LOCATION_ID_OSHAWA), 5000);
        }
        private static void PopulateLocations()
        {
            Location oshawa = new Location(LOCATION_ID_OSHAWA, "Oshawa");
            Location toronto = new Location(LOCATION_ID_TORONTO, "Toronto");

            Locations.Add(oshawa);
            Locations.Add(toronto);
        }
        public static Location LocationByID(int id)
        {
            foreach (Location location in Locations)
            {
                if (location.ID == id)
                {
                    return location;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you actually setting the view model properties? World.TrueDay and World.Player1.PlayerMoney aren't bound to a view, and they don't trigger any view model property setters.

Comment: I set the properties in my World class and initialize them in the App.xaml.cs.
```c#

Comment: Update the question to include where you're setting one of the bound properties

Comment: It's updated, thanks in advance

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: changing the value of `World.Player1.PlayerMoney` is not going to cause the `PropertyChanged` event of the `Money` property in your VM to fire.  You could try manually calling `OnPropertyChanged(Money)` in `On1Turn` to force it.  This is just a really bizarre design

Comment: @jordan1300 Not finding changing model code in `ToolbarItem_Clicked`.You should check that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT you were correct I was only updating my Model and not my ViewModel. I changed the code to update both during the On1Turn Method in my view model and connected that to the button via data bindings since I now know they are 100% working. Now when I click the button to add a turn they day goes up by one as it should however the money doesn't update. I put a break point and I know the value is updating but OnPropertyChanged is not firing. I updated the HomePageViewModel.cs to reflect the changes I've made if you have any insight as to why.

Comment: @Jason Yeah after reading your comment as well as others I realized I was never updating the ViewModel in the method just the model. I changed the code for the On1Turn method to update both the view model and the model. Now the days are working as expected but the money value still doesn't seem to want to update and I've tried re writing the code and even giving it it's own variable rather than referencing the actual player money property in the VM but nothing has worked. I've update my view model in my original question to reflect the changes I've made if you'd care to take a look.

Comment: OnPropertyChanged(“Money”);

Comment: Holy.. Just realized I wasn't changing the proper value in the method, should have been changing the value of the Money property not the MoneyValue property. All is working as intended. Thanks All for the assistance!

Comment: @Jason Thanks a bunch for the help it's all working now!

Comment: @jordan1300 Glad you have solved it ! That's a good news.If answer be helpful thanks for marking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not too understanding logic about project, but if want to change model data can do as follow

**HomePage.xaml.cs**:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        HomePageViewModel homePageViewModel = new HomePageViewModel();
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = homePageViewModel ;
        }

        private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            homePageViewModel.CurrentDay = xxx ;

            homePageViewModel.xxxxx = xxxx;
            //Something like this can change model data
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959818/data-binding-part-of-a-label-in-xamarin-forms/52960327#52960327) data binding discussion can be refer to.